# How to make UITableView work within TTScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, three20, scrollview

I'm solving a problem how to make tableviews work within three20's TTScrollView. I have a project which I want to rebuild using three20 library. There is one module which allows user to flip through set of "pages", which contains table showing some list of data.

My problem is that when I rebuilt this module to use three20's TTScrollView, tableviews inside the scrollview do not work anymore. In particular, it cannot be scrolled and cannot select an item, because all touches are intercepted by the scrollview. I'm getting mad about this and cannot figure out how to make it work.

I'm able to make work either tableview or scrollview but not both (means tableview intercepts vertical dragging, while scrollview horizontal). It worked fine with UIKit's UIScrollview, so there must be a way how to do this, but simply cannot figure out how.

Please help, I'm struggling with it yet couple of days now, but cannot get over.

thanks much for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Matthes,

Unfortunately not many people here at SO help out much with three20 questions for whatever reason.  You may have better luck asking the three20 google group (search for that on google).

First guess though without trying it myself:  try using three20's built in table items such as `TTTableTextItem` or `TTTableImageItem` ...in certain scenarios with three20, he has built in code to ignore everything you write except for his own built in controls (which might be the case here, not sure).

You can see examples of how he creates tables with this code in the TTCatalog example app that you can find via www.three20.info

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to ask in three20's forum already, but was not successful so far, so I tried my luck here as well. What you suggest does not apply on my situation.
Issue here is simply the fact that both tableview as well as scrollview grabs all user's actions and doesn't pass events to it's subviews. What I need is to figure out if user is moving up/down rather than left/right and pass events to underlaying tableview in that case. I know how to determine direction of movements, but don't know how to make the scrollview to stop respond and let the tableview handle the events.

Comment: In that case, you may want to post another question and phrase it differently (i.e. without any reference to three20).  Unfortunately I don't know much about sending events up the responder chain, but that is basically what you are wanting to do.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.